# Vim doesn't highlight some words

Tags: c++, vim, plugins, ide, highlight

I'm using the [TagHighlight](http://www.cgtk.co.uk/vim-scripts/taghighlight) plugin in Vim to get highlighting of my custom C++ classes and members.

This trick I found [there](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Identify_the_syntax_highlighting_group_used_at_the_cursor) allowed me to better understand how Vim considered certain words. In a way I can ask it now: "Okay, why have you put *this* word in green?"

The strange thing is that it works well, except for (many) random cases, see:

[image]

My library's namespace `sf` has been highlighted, and Vim tells `hi<CTagsNamespace> trans<CTagsNamespace> lo<Constant>` when I ask it why, great.

But the `std` hasn't, and the answer is `hi<> trans<cParen> lo<>`.

My variable `angle` has been spotted as a `hi<CTagsMember> trans<CTagsMember> lo<Member>` (why not?), but its little bro' `speed` hasn't: it is `hi<> trans<cBlock> lo<>`.

So.. why? Is there a way Vim can actually read and understand my whole project, then highlight it the proper way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From TagHighlight description:

> TagHighlight is a plugin that highlights names of classes, variables,
>   types etc in source code in Vim.  This makes it quicker and easier to
>   spot errors in your code.  *By using exuberant ctags and parsing the*
>   *output*, the typedefs, #defines, enumerated names etc are all clearly
>   highlighted in different colours.

You probably doesn't have the source for the std namespace, therefore no tags and thus no highlight.

Your ctags probably is not generating tags for local variables, thus speed gets no highlight. But you probably has a variable named angles as global or member variable, thus the local variable angle gets highlighted by accident.

And don't blame Vim, this is probably something to do about the plugin and your tags :)

Comment: Oh, I never meant to blame Vim (I f+kg love it!). If I understand well, I just need to find support for the `std` namespace (I think `TagHighlight` actually provides it), and to accept some occasional misinterpretations.. okay! :) .. Just to make sure then (and I don't mean to blame anything here): this means Vim doesn't actually *understand* I'm using `angle` as a plain local variable. And there seems to be no way to "teach" it yet :/

Comment: @Iago-lito I doesn't read the plugin code, but I believe it uses a list of identifiers to apply the highlights; the list is obtained from ctags, so if ctags is not executed upon std code (or headers, at least) them it won't be present on the list to highlight. From this list it probably highlight all the words on the screen that matches that list -- it doesn't check for the context, so it is unable to understand that a local variable has the same name as a member field.